# Was the location of Chicken Shop Date witheld when Cher was on since she slagged it off?

Tags: chicken-shop-date

This the [Cher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkffkAD_xGo) episode of *Chicken Shop Date*, I noticed they didn't show details of the location or workers, as I thought they normally do.

Is this because they wanted to avoid the bad publicity, since Cher was fairly critical of it?

Comment: Probably the owners asked her not to show it.

Comment: That is my guess, but I have no evidence, maybe someone else has seen some.